# A Twist on A Directional Derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am working on a question that asks me to find a direction $v$ so that the directional derivative of $f(x,y) = xe^{xy}+y$, at the point $P=(2,0)$, is seven.

I've computed that the gradient of $f$ at $P$ is $(1,1)$, so the directional derivative is the dot product of $(1,1)$ and a vector $v$, but I am getting stumped on trying to find its components.

Vector $v$ has to be a unit vector so it would be $(x,y)$ divided by its norm:

$$v = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} , \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).$$

Then I set the dot product as:

$$(1, 1) \cdot \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} , \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) = 7,$$

and now to simplify everything:

$$\frac{\left(x+y\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 7$$

$$x+y=7\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$\left(x+y\right)^2=49\left(x^2+y^2\right)$$

$$x^2+2xy+y^2=49x^2+49y^2$$

$$2xy=48x^2+48y^2$$

So you're left with: $xy=24x^2+24y^2$.

I don't know how to proceed since there is no system of equations and I have two variables here.

Comment: The directional derivative is an operation on a *function*, not on a single vector. So I don't know what it even means for a vector $v$ to have directional derivative of 7 in the $(i,j)$ direction.

Comment: @user7530 maybe seeing the question would help: [question 4](https://ibb.co/ydDSLTS). i calculated (i+j) from the partial derivatives of the given funtion and i need to find a vector (v) that gives a dot product of 7 with (i+j). we already have the directional derivative but we need to find a unit vector that gives it with (i+j)

Comment: Where is the function $f$ in your question?

Comment: it is the f(x,y) = $f\left(x,y\right)=xe^{xy\ }+y$

Comment: I've improved your question; in the future, if you want help from this site, please take the time to write your question professionally: (1) include all details from the problem you are trying to solve; (2) typeset your math using Latex, (3) use complete sentences, (4) use proper spelling and grammar, such as capitalizing the pronoun "I".

Comment: The gradient at $(2,0)$ is $(1,5)$, not $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see what you're doing. You already computed $\nabla f(P) = (1,1)$ and now are trying to find a unit vector $v$ with
$$(1,1) \cdot v = 7.$$

There are several ways to proceed from your calculations.

1) Try to solve for $x$, as a function of $y$, by applying the quadratic formula. What can you conclude about the expression you get? Is there any possible real solution $(x,y)$?

2) Go back to the expression $(1,1)\cdot v$, where you know $\|v\|=1$. Is there any convenient bound you can place on the magnitude of the dot product?

3) Instead of $(x,y)$, write your vector as $(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$. Try to solve for $\theta$.